# ActiveRecord Connection Base execute

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, activerecord

Active record connection base execute returns Mysql2::Result object which has an each method available to iterate over the values, I have around half a million records returned for every query and I would like to achieve the same speed as Array iteration but the each of Mysql2::Result is very slow (5x times slower) compared to Array iteration. I can't afford to convert to array and then iterate as converting to array itself takes a long time(around 35 secs). Is there a better way to deal with the same?

The query execution takes around 2 secs which is fine but I really need to reduce the computation time?